# aligning the decimal places in the presence of signs and asterisks in a table

Tags: tables, align

I must admit and say that I am a latex rookie. I am trying to create a latex table where in each cell I have decimal numbers sign symbol and some asterisks. With the code I shared above, I am not able to align them in a nice way. The table looks terrible.

Is there a way to align them and make it looking more beautiful? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code and table:

[image]

```
\begin{table}[t!]
%\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc@{}}
\toprule
 &   & MMM & NNN & ATTT & PRS \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{X} & Coef & -0.010$^{*}$ & -0.010$^{*}$ & -0.002 & 0.001 \\
 & AAA & 0.080 & 0.082 & 0.010 & 0.018 \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Y} & Coef & 0.006 & 0.002 & 0.001 & -0.003$^{***}$ \\
 & AAA & 0.037 & 0.003 & 0.020 & 0.523 \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Z} & Coef & 0.005 & 0.001 & 0.001$^{*}$ & 0.001 \\
&  AAA & 0.049 & 0.070 & 0.070 & 0.014 \\
\multirow{2}{*}{T} & Coef & 0.016 & 0.019 & 0.015 & -0.001 \\
 & AAA & 0.023 & 0.029 & 0.073 & 0.048 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Model Fit (R2)} & 0.19 & 0.17 & 0.17 & 0.60 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502017/table-does-not-flush-right-with-siunitx-table-format-esttab-asterisks-and-in

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24839/align-numbers-with-numbers-and-asterisks-in-table-by-decimal-point

Comment: Hello there! I'm Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related.

Comment: Which documentclass do you currently use? Why do you reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` to 2pt? Your table fits perfectly fine into the textwidth of a standard article class even without reducing the distance between the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `siunitx` in order to align the numbers with respect to the decimal marker. I have also included a second example table with a slightly different layout that does not use `\multirow`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \sisetup{table-format = -1.3, table-space-text-post=$^{*}$}
    \begin{tabular}{llSSSS[table-space-text-post=$^{***}$]}
        \toprule
        &   & {MMM} & {NNN} & {ATTT} & {PRS} \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{X} & Coef & -0.010$^{*}$ & -0.010$^{*}$ & -0.002 & 0.001 \\
        & AAA & 0.080 & 0.082 & 0.010 & 0.018 \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Y} & Coef & 0.006 & 0.002 & 0.001 & -0.003$^{***}$ \\
        & AAA & 0.037 & 0.003 & 0.020 & 0.523 \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Z} & Coef & 0.005 & 0.001 & 0.001$^{*}$ & 0.001 \\
        &  AAA & 0.049 & 0.070 & 0.070 & 0.014 \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{T} & Coef & 0.016 & 0.019 & 0.015 & -0.001 \\
        & AAA & 0.023 & 0.029 & 0.073 & 0.048 \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Model Fit (R2)} & 0.19 & 0.17 & 0.17 & 0.60 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
 \sisetup{table-format = -1.3, table-space-text-post=$^{*}$}
    \begin{tabular}{llSSSS[table-space-text-post=$^{***}$]}
        \toprule
        &   & {MMM} & {NNN} & {ATTT} & {PRS} \\ \midrule
        X & Coef & -0.010$^{*}$ & -0.010$^{*}$ & -0.002 & 0.001 \\
        & AAA & 0.080 & 0.082 & 0.010 & 0.018 \\ \addlinespace
        Y & Coef & 0.006 & 0.002 & 0.001 & -0.003$^{***}$ \\
        & AAA & 0.037 & 0.003 & 0.020 & 0.523 \\ \addlinespace
        Z & Coef & 0.005 & 0.001 & 0.001$^{*}$ & 0.001 \\
        &  AAA & 0.049 & 0.070 & 0.070 & 0.014 \\ \addlinespace
        T & Coef & 0.016 & 0.019 & 0.015 & -0.001 \\
        & AAA & 0.023 & 0.029 & 0.073 & 0.048 \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Model Fit (R2)} & 0.19 & 0.17 & 0.17 & 0.60 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\sisetup{table-format = -1.3}
\begin{table}[t!]
    %\small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{lcSSSS@{}}
        \toprule
        &   & MMM & NNN & ATTT & PRS \\ \midrule
        \multirow{2}{*}{X} & Coef & -0.010$^{*}$ & -0.010$^{*}$ & -0.002 & 0.001 \\
        & AAA & 0.080 & 0.082 & 0.010 & 0.018 \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Y} & Coef & 0.006 & 0.002 & 0.001 & -0.003$^{***}$ \\
        & AAA & 0.037 & 0.003 & 0.020 & 0.523 \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Z} & Coef & 0.005 & 0.001 & 0.001$^{*}$ & 0.001 \\
        &  AAA & 0.049 & 0.070 & 0.070 & 0.014 \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{T} & Coef & 0.016 & 0.019 & 0.015 & -0.001 \\
        & AAA & 0.023 & 0.029 & 0.073 & 0.048 \\ \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Model Fit (R2)} & 0.19 & 0.17 & 0.17 & 0.60 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same but ignore the row defined with toprule?